# Pass values from inner recursive methods to outer methods

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, sum, powerset

I found the following method from http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/ which prints all the subsets in an array that sum to a certain number.

My code  is full of print statements which I used to trace the recursive calls:

```
public static void find(int[] A, int currSum, int index, int sum,
        int[] solution, int tot) {
    if (currSum == sum) {
                    tot +=1;

        System.out.println("\nSum found ");
        for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            if (solution[i] == 1) {
                System.out.print("  " + A[i]);
            }
        }

    } else if (index == A.length) {
                System.out.println("reached end");
        return;
    } else {
        solution[index] = 1;// select the element
        currSum += A[index];
                    System.out.println("incr " + A[index] + "  "+ currSum + " ");
        find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution, tot);
        currSum -= A[index];
                    System.out.println("decr " + A[index] + "  "+ currSum + " ");
        solution[index] = 0;// do not select the element
        find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution, tot);
    }
    return;            
}
```

I want to modify the method so that it also prints the final number of solutions in the end.
I know this question has been discussed on Stackoverflow and I found some interesting solutions. Nevertheless, I want to find out whether there is a way to modify this particular method. 
My idea was to create an integer "tot" to which I add 1 as soon as I find a solution and then pass the updated value to every recursive call. But the final value will be found in one of the inner recursive calls and I don't know how to pass the final value to the outer methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a solution count in recursive calls, best way would be to pass a mutable reference in each method call. As soon as you get a solution, update the mutable reference. Here, mutable reference is important because:

1. primitive types would be hard to propagate through recursive calls as return types will need to be maintained and updated accordingly.
2. immutable types (like `Integer`) will not maintain values across recursive calls.

**Solutions:**

1. Use `AtomicInteger`
2. Use primitive `int` array

Both will be able to solve your problem. You should check for `null` reference or length of array to make it less error prone. Samples given below:

```
private static void methodWithAtomicInteger(AtomicInteger i){
    i.incrementAndGet();
}

private static void methodWithIntArray(int[] i){
    i[0]++;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(0);
    System.out.println(integer);
    methodWithAtomicInteger(integer);
    System.out.println(integer);

    int[] values = new int[]{0};
    System.out.println(values[0]);
    methodWithIntArray(values);
    System.out.println(values[0]);
}
```